# При автоматизированной сборке на gitlab программа теряет расширение exe, почему это происходит и как решить?

Tags: python, gitlab, pyinstaller, exe, gitlab-ci

У меня есть проект на языке python. Он лежит на gitlab. Я иногда делаю коммиты с указанием версии программы, и хотел бы чтобы у меня проект собирался сразу после этого в полноценную программу, но обнаружил проблему. Почему то после сборки через pyinstaller у результирующей программы (той собственно которую я и собираю) исчезает расширение exe. У меня на компе при тех же настройках pyinstaller собирает все без проблем и на выходе лежит нормальная программа, а там почему то это не происходит. В чем дело? можно как то решить эту проблему?

**Дополнение:**

У меня получилось установить wine и поставить на него python версии 3.4.3 но при попытке вызвать pip появляется ошибка.

```
Collecting pyinstaller Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/b5/79e53c645c3f458cde165493ed71c1cac478fce67f204ad6ecca48b47440/pyinstaller-6.3.0.tar.gz Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 20, in <module Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 20, in <module

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\users\gitlab-runner\Temp\pip-build-pab05uix\pyinstaller
0090:err:rpc:I_RpcReceive we got fault packet with status 0x1c010003
```

На данный момент такой код ошибки если запускать на 3.4.3 и 3.1 через команду wine pip install

При попытках запустить через python -m pip install pyinstaller такая ошибка

```
$ wine python -m pip install pyinstaller C:\Python31\python.exe: No module named pip
```

**Дополнение 2**

При установке конкретной версии pyinstaller такой трэйс:

```
$ wine pip install "pyinstaller==3.1.1"
You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 23.3.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting pyinstaller==3.1.1
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/7f/e2f744ba13d7a27360a43b62d3d9aeff7df1d7fa346f746fc040a0caf9e3/PyInstaller-3.1.1.tar.gz (2.8MB)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller==3.1.1)
Collecting pypiwin32 (from pyinstaller==3.1.1)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/1b/2f292bbd742e369a100c91faa0483172cd91a1a422a6692055ac920946c5/pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32->pyinstaller==3.1.1)
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32->pyinstaller==3.1.1)
  No distributions at all found for pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32->pyinstaller==3.1.1)
0090:err:rpc:I_RpcReceive we got fault packet with status 0x1c010003
```

**Дополнение 3**

Попробовал просто обновить pip до последней версии через команду `wine pip install --upgrade pip`
Получил такой трейсер:

```
Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 371, in _rmtree_unsafe
      os.unlink(fullname)
  PermissionError: [WinError 5] ������ ��������: 'C:\\users\\gitlab-runner\\Temp\\pip-a4jy95k_-uninstall\\python34\\scripts\\pip.exe'
  
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 232, in main
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 347, in run
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 560, in install
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 680, in commit_uninstall
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_uninstall.py", line 153, in commit
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 212, in call
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 247, in get
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\six.py", line 659, in reraise
      _assertCountEqual = "assertCountEqual"
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 200, in call
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 61, in rmtree
    File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 478, in rmtree
      return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 368, in _rmtree_unsafe
      _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 368, in _rmtree_unsafe
      _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 373, in _rmtree_unsafe
      onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 73, in rmtree_errorhandler
  PermissionError: [WinError 5] ������ ��������: 'C:\\users\\gitlab-runner\\Temp\\pip-a4jy95k_-uninstall\\python34\\scripts\\pip.exe'
```

Comment: Ну gitlab скорее всего на linux запущен. При запуске под linux pyinstaller создает исполняемый файл для linux. Исполняемый файл не только расширение "теряет", у него вообще другой формат.

Comment: Теоретически указание cmd или powershell в качестве shell может помочь: [Selecting your shell](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html#selecting-your-shell), [Types of shells supported by GitLab Runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/). Но это не точно. В целом как-то нужно настроить, чтобы был windows раннер, а не linux.

Comment: нет на гитлаб запущен windows, и дело в том что программа исполняемый файл именно без расширения, там никакого нет

Comment: Если расширение добавить, будет запускаться?

Comment: неа, что странно

Comment: Тогда пробуйте настроить шелл.

Comment: выдает что нельзя запустить данную программу

Comment: хорошо попробую

Comment: да я ошибся, оказывается стоит линукс. Недавно со всем этим работаю, плохо разбираюсь во всем этом. Вопрос такой, а можно как то pyinstaller указать что нужен именно exe?

Comment: Вроде бы никак. В [этом ответе от 2016 года](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35605479/4752653) упоминается, что такая возможность когда-то была, но была выпилена начиная с версии 1.5. Ну и предлагается использовать wine для сборки. Я думаю, теоретически можно в gitlab настроить windows раннер, и билдить из него, но как это на практике сделать еще нужно разбираться.

Comment: не получается сделать как на этом посту, у меня получилось поставить на wine python3.1 но когда вызывал pip для установки pyinstaller возникла такая ошибка: 

$ cd ~/.wine/drive_c/Python31
$ wine python.exe Scripts/pip.exe install pyinstaller
C:\Python31\python.exe: can't open file 'Scripts/pip.exe': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

В чем проблема?

Comment: Пробуйте через `python -m pip install pyinstaller`

Comment: Python можно посвежее использовать, хотя бы Python 3.5, вот тут слева можно посмотреть поддерживаемые версии: https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/3.1.1/

Comment: в версиях посвежее нет msi установщика, из-за чего на wine их не поставить

Comment: Вот для Python 3.4.3 есть: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-343/

Comment: $ wine python -m pip install --upgrade pip
C:\Python31\python.exe: No module named pip

я попробовал его так запустить, но не выходит.

Comment: Пробуйте на Python 3.4.3, на 3.1 похоже еще не было pip.

Comment: Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/b5/79e53c645c3f458cde165493ed71c1cac478fce67f204ad6ecca48b47440/pyinstaller-6.3.0.tar.gz
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module

ошибка такая же была и на 3.1 запускал просто написав pip instal, если писать python -m pip пишет нет модуля

Comment: Нужно целиком трэйс смотреть, по этому куску ничего понять нельзя

Comment: отправил трэйсы в другом ответе, тут не получилось изза ограничения символов

Comment: Устанавливайте 3.1.1 версию: `pip install "pyinstaller==3.1.1"`

Comment: дополнил вопрос выводом

Comment: Пробуйте тогда еще более старые версии pyinstaller, 3.1 и ниже. См. историю версий тут: https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/#history

Comment: я попробовал, старые версии выдают ошибки. Есть возможность установить pip отдельно от питона? Так же например через msi...  может его другие версии нормально работать будут

Comment: У вас есть pip, не нужно его отдельно устанавливать. Проблема с pyinstaller и его зависимостями.

Comment: в таком случае в чем еще может быть ошибка?

Comment: Хз, я же не вижу все ошибки что у вас происходят. Я бы вернулся настройке gitlab раннера, с docker-windows экзекьютором: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html